# akka-http stops accepting incoming connections when actors are heavily used

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

akka-http stops accepting incoming connections when one of my actors is heavily busy. I suspect I'm blocking for too long in my actors or something like that. How can I debug it to pinpoint the problem ?

I don't have much in my config which is below

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = DEBUG
  http.host-connection-pool {
    max-connections = 8
    client {
      proxy {
        http {
          host = localhost
          port = 8888
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

http {
  interface = "0.0.0.0"
  port = 8080
}

services {
  proxyHost = "localhost"
  proxyPort = 8118
}

bounded-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
  mailbox-capacity = 100
  mailbox-push-timeout-time = 5000ms
}
```

I use `bounded-mailbox` for actor that does DB-extensive work. I'm on akka 2.4.6

Comment: `I suspect I'm blocking for too long in my actors` You shouldn't be blocking in actors at all. We need to see your code. Your config doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @Falmarri Well, of course I don't explicitly block anything. The actor in question is ingesting data it's scraping from external web-sites. I use apache http-async-client. Everything is wrapped into `Promise`s and responses handled in `Future` completion handlers. So it's not obvious to me what's wrong. Is there way to debug it other than meditating on the code ?

Comment: Maybe try to prepare mcve, you might even find the solution yourself in the process of doing it. You can try to take a look at https://www.lightbend.com/products/monitoring or http://kamon.io/

Comment: @expert: Why are you using http-async-client instead of akka-http client? And it's impossible to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: @Falmarri Because akka-http client is rudimentary client which is not production ready for anything more complex than making simple request. No support of redirects, cookies and etc.